# Pytest - pass fixture to mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

The objective is to parametrize over a set of objects, and for each object further parametrize for all tests (varying from 1 to N). My objects can be very large, which is why I do not want to load all objects in one go. Number of tests should be equal to the number of keys in `tests` for all objects, as opposed to being the number of objects.

Currently I'm trying to do this by passing a fixture into a mark.parametrize to generate a list of tests to run over. But this does not work as within `pytest.mark.parametrize` it sees `some_fixture` as a function and I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'list_of_tuples'`

Sample code:

```
dict = {
    'obj1': {
        'tests': {'a1': 'b1', 'a2':'b2'}
    },
    'obj2': {
        'tests': {'a3':'b3', 'a4':'b4', 'a5':'b5'}
    }
}

class RandomClass():
    def __init__(self, name, dict):
        self._obj_name = name
        self._dict = dict

        self.list_of_tuples = None

    def create_list_of_tuples(self):
        self.list_of_tuples = []
        for item in self._dict[self._obj_name]['tests']:
            self.list_of_tuples.append((item, self._dict[self._obj_name]['tests'][item]))


@pytest.fixture(params=list(dict.keys())
def some_fixture(request, dict):
    obj = RandomClass(name = request.param, dict=dict)
    obj.create_list_of_tuples()
    return obj

@pytest.mark.parametrize("var1, var2", some_fixture.list_of_tuples, indirect=True)
def test_something(var1, var2):

   assert var1 == var2
```

Many thanks.